# uwp loading config from a file at startup

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to load some data (from a configuration file) at startup. The onlys way to acces file in win 10 uwp is to use async method.

Great, but:

How can'I call an async method in a constructor (this is not possible, I know) or any equivalent. Here is my actual code.

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{

    public ITrackThatContext Context { get; private set; }        
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

        Context = await LocalFileTrackThatContext.CreateAsync(null);
    }
}
```

I can call the `Context = await LocalFileTrackThatContext.CreateAsync(null);` from a button on the first page of the app, but I'm sure there is better to do. Is there any entry point for launching a task from the startup process. I read [startup stages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/best-practices-for-your-app-s-startup-performance#introduction-to-the-stages-of-startup), but I can't figure out where to load my conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there could be other places, the most convenient is in `OnNavigatedTo` method of the first page that you load.

EDIT: If you need this to be done just once you can have one Page with just `Frame` inside it from which you then navigate to other pages. Or you can somewhere store a bool value whether the operation is completed or not and act based upon that.

Comment: `OnNavigateTo` is not async ? Did I missunderstand your answer ?

Comment: @tschmit007 It can be async just like any other method you just add a word async when you override it. But constructors can't be async as they aren't methods.

Comment: @tschmit007 use the OnNavigateTo is better.

Comment: I'm trying with `OnLoaded`, but it seems that a new instance of the page is created on each navigation action.

Comment: @tschmit007 it does. As a workaround you can have one page with just a Frame inside from which you load and navigate other pages.

Answer (score 1):

Define a callback method and provide that to Task.ContinueWith():

```
LocalFileTrackThatContext.CreateAsync(null).ContinueWith(contextLoaded);
```

In this case, the rest of the constructor should assume Context is not yet set - anything that needs to wait until Context is known will happen in the callback.

The callback method is passed a Task argument, and it can get .Result and .Status from there.

Comment: ty for the "astuce" of avoiding async in the calling method. But not (yet) my solution